# Quote Generator by Date

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm trying to make a quote generator that generates different quotes depending on the date on the calendar year.  This is what I came up with so far:

```
<b id="texts">&nbsp;</b> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var quote = ["", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",     "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25",
"26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"]; 
quote[0]=""; quote[1]="1"; quote[2]="2"; quote[3]="3"; quote[4]="4"; 
quote[5]="5"; 
quote[6]="6"; quote[7]="7"; quote[8]="8"; quote[9]="9"; 
quote[10]="10"; quote[11]="11"; 
quote[12]="12"; quote[13]="13"; quote[14]="14"; quote[15]="15"; 
quote[16]="16"; quote[17]="17"; 
quote[18]="18"; quote[19]="19"; quote[20]="20"; quote[21]="21"; 
quote[22]="22"; quote[23]="23"; 
quote[24]="24"; quote[25]="25"; quote[26]="26"; quote[27]="27"; 
quote[28]="28"; quote[29]="29"; 
quote[30]="30"; quote[31]="31";

function LoadDate() { 
        start = new Date("December 1,2014");
        future = new Date("December 31, 2013");
        range = []
        mil = 86400000 //24h
        for (var i=start.getTime(); i<future.getTime();i=i+mil) {

          range.push(new Date(i))
} 

window.onload = LoadDate; 
</script>
```

Unfortunately, I have found that this set up is not functional at all.  I am awfully green when it comes to coding, so I can't exactly figure out what the problem is here.  I think I may be close to the solution I want, but I'm having trouble tying up the loose ends here.  Help?

Comment: Not a good idea to create dates using a non–standard string, much better to do `new Date(2014, 11, 1)` for 1 December, 2014.

Comment: It seems that it is not exactly working even with the new "new Date" definition.  Thanks for the advice, though.  I will keep that in mind for any future exercises I attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find your code quite confusing.

What I would do is use property lookup, something like this: [**Live demo (click).**](http://jsbin.com/EQuKUpED/1/edit)

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth();
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
//month = 11;
//day = 25'

var quotes = {
  '11' : {
    '24': "It's Christmas Eve!",
    '25': 'Merry Christmas!',
    '26': 'Christmas is over.'
  }
};

var quoteElem = document.createElement('p');
quoteElem.textContent = quotes[month][day];

document.body.appendChild(quoteElem);
```

The objects could be arrays instead. Either way..

Here, I'm just looking up the quote according to the month and day, but this could easily be adapted to anything. It would still follow the principle of using the date to lookup the quote by it's key in the object/array. The possibilities are quite vast.

If you want to associate quotes to multiple dates, you could store the date association along with the quotes, then look through the dates for a match to the current day: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/EQuKUpED/4/edit)**

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth();
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
//month = 11;
//day = 25'

var quotes = [
  {
    quote:"It's a day!",
    dates: [
      '11/25',
      '2/4'
    ]
  },
  {
    quote:"It's another day!",
    dates: [
      '11/26',
      '5/14'
    ]
  }
];

var date = month+'/'+day;
var quote;
for (var i=0; i<quotes.length; ++i) {
  if (quotes[i].dates.indexOf(date) !== -1) {
    quote = quotes[i].quote; 
  }
}

var quoteElem = document.createElement('p');
quoteElem.textContent = quote;

document.body.appendChild(quoteElem);
```

Comment: Thank you for linking me to that website because it seems to work for me better than the site I was previously using.  And thank you for the advice as well because this seems to be a more refined way to achieve what I'm looking to do.  Again, I am still very new at this, so I expected to find better ways to create what I am trying to do than the way that I was doing it.  The script I had worked when I had it basically count to 31, but it started to fail when I tried to tie the dates of more than one month to it.  Again, thank you for the solution to the small exercise I am doing.

Comment: @user3076531 My updated answer might also help! I see you're new to Stack Overflow. If my answer is helpful you can upvote it. It is also good to choose the most helpful answer and accept it with the checkmark so that other people are encouraged to check it out if they have the same issue.

Comment: Sadly, I can't upvote until I have 15 rep 'cause, otherwise, I would.